# Control a servo through the flight controller PPM output and a ppm to pwm card

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, betaflight

I have a quadcopter on which I want to connect a servo, I bought a ppm to multiple PWM converter to connect on the flight controller PPM output, but I don't find how to tell betaflight to control the servo through the converter.

I tried to configure the servo in the servo tab but it does nothing.

Comment: Why are you using a PPM to PWM converter? The "ppm" on the board is an input (unless remapped with resource mapping) and betaflight/inav do not output PPM. You want to connect your servo to a "motor" output and look into the servo mappings to those motor outputs

Comment: @BrydonGibson Ok, I understand better know, I think I can't do that with this FC even if there's several pins that are physically available there's no documentation. Thanks

Comment: Look into the "resource" CLI command in betaflight. You can use it to figure out mappings based on what the target developer has decided for this board. Effectively, it _is_ the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Flight controllers usually have PPM *inputs*, not outputs. The PPM output is on your radio module.

You can indeed connect the PPM output signal to both the FC and your PPM->PWM converter: the FC would be controlling the motors, and the converter would be controlling the servo. There's nothing to configure in Betaflight in this case: the value from a certain channel will be applied directly to the servo.

A better idea is to configure Betaflight to control your servo: this avoids using the converter altogether, saving space, weight an money. If you have 1 or 2 servors to control, it's recommended to use `feature SERVO_TILT`, otherwise `CHANNEL_FORWARDING` is an option. [Here](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/wiki/Servos-&-SERVO_TILT-for-3.1)'s the Betaflight documentation page with examples. Note that you need to assign resources (pins with timers) to servos before you can use them.